# Is $.empty() enough for big ajaxy apps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, memory

Been working on an App and since it's getting a bit too big I've thinking of ways to improve memory management since the app runs mostly on Javascipt. So every time a navigation item is clicked I would call the jquery empty then show the html via ajax. ex:

```
//$.ajaxSetup(); called before this
//$this is the attached element 
$.ajax({success:function(data){
    $this.empty().html(data.output).fadeIn(400);
    //more javascript stuff like loading tinymce or jquery ui
}});
```

is this enough to prevent memory leaks? I'm not entirely sure what empty does but I'm assuming it removes all DOM elements within that div along with any other objects and events? btw. You can find the app here http://webproposalgenerator.com/ and http://webproposalgenerator.com/demo.

any tips on improving the performance/security or any feedback at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have memory leaks or this is only an academic discussion? You can use developer tools in modern browsers to check for memory leaks. If you are not sure what `.empty()` does then here is the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/empty/). It removes children elements and their data and event handlers and the element themselves.

Comment: What browser(s) is/are showing behavior that looks like memory leaks?

Comment: There aren't any memory leaks yet, I just wanted to plan for it since I'm redoing most of the core framework. I know in PHP, unset() is the way to go when trying to clear memory blocks, is there a javascipt/jquery equivalent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$.fn.empty` should be enough, it deletes all data and events associated to the elements and then deletes the elements. It also calls `.widget("destroy")` on all jquery-ui widget.js based widgets that are defined on those elements.

It is also important to note that jquery's `$.fn.html` method calls `$.fn.empty()` on the given element before appending html, therefore, if you are using `$.fn.html`, you don't have to call `$.fn.empty`

Answer (score 1):

actually my guess was that .`html` implies .`empty` anyway, also I'm not sure that's true. for the perforamnce part: according to [jqfundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/) excelent book it is a recommanded best practice to add content while the element is in `.detach()` from the DOM. tried to lock at the code for advice but didn't find it. nice site btw