# Is necessary to call empty() before html() or before innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a popup plugin which sets the html content of a `<div/>` with the response of an AJAX call.

Every time i open the popup, in the code i just call `$("#popup").html(response)`. This overrides the existing html content with the new content.

Should i call `$("popup").empty()` before i call `$("popup").html(response)` so i release the browser memory used by the objects which were previously in the `$("popup")` div? (eventually prevent memory leaks)

PS: what if i call `$("popup")[0].innerHTML = response` ? should i call `.empty()` method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567957/is-empty-enough-for-big-ajaxy-apps?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer no.

`jQuery.fn.html` uses `DOMNode.innerHTML =` after doing several other things. One is to remove any stored data on nodes (stored via `$.fn.data`), see http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.html for full source overview.

`.innerHTML` removes the children and replaces with the new html. But beware of memory leaks. I would use `jQuery.fn.empty` before setting innerHTML. eg.

```
var a = document.createElement('div'),
    b = document.createElement('div');

    b.appendChild(a);

    b.innerHTML = 'new innerHMTL'.
```

You would think everything is ok. But the node replaces/removed is still captured in the varible `a` and therefore isn't thrown to the garbage collector. I'm not sure wether or not that jQuery stores DOMNodes internal until you call `jQuery.removeData` etc.

Answer (score 5):

JQuery documentation of html method says:

> When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content. Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the new content.

So you don't need to call `empty()`.

Answer (score 2):

No need to call `empty()`.`html`(`response`) method `ovverides` the [existing content](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Answer (score 0):

No difference except .empty() runs faster and .html() can overwrite the content of the context

http://jsperf.com/jquery-empty-vs-html/17